# How to run cargo fmt on save in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-cargo

Is it possible to make Visual Studio Code run `cargo fmt` on file save?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Install the extension rust-analyzer (the [officially recommended](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools) vscode extension), and add the following to settings.json:

```
"[rust]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Answer (score 26):

1. Install [rust-analyzer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=matklad.rust-analyzer), if you have not already.
2. In Visual Studio Code's settings, enable **Editor: Format On Save** (`editor.formatOnSave`).

Comment: I'll also add that you should ensure you don't have "editor.defaultFormatter" set globally. If you have, say, "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" (or some other formatter) enabled globally rather than on a per-language basis, VSCode will attempt to use that formatter in lieu of rust-analyzer's on Rust code. I've seen a few JS devs lost 10 or 15 minutes to this when transitioning to a Rust project.

Answer (score 21):

This is what worked for me. In the file settings.json somewhere inside the curly braces insert the following :

```
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "rust-analyzer.rustfmt.enableRangeFormatting": true,
    "[rust]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer", 
        "editor.formatOnSave": true 
    },
```

Answer (score 12):

If you have **formatOnSaveMode** is set to **modifications** or **modificationsIfAvailable**, you may need to change it to **file**. This is probably a small issue with the analyzer.

And if you want to leave the default settings unchanged, do it for only rust;

```
"[rust]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"
  },
```

Comment: i just need to add: "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "file"
it's the working answer! thank you!

Comment: This was it for me, thanks! With modifications set it silently did nothing.

Answer (score 9):

Current version of the Rust extension > 0.7.8 requires nothing else to be installed. Enable `formatOnSave` in VS Code `settings.json` file:

```json
  "[rust]": {
        "editor.formatOnSave": true
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Install rust-analyzer and add this to your `settings.json`

```json
"[rust]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of Delta Kapp's answer above.